# Sitemap cakephp com Rotas

Tags: cakephp, sitemap

Ao invés de ficar fazendo sitemap na unha, é possível fazer um método dentro do meu routes, que, todas páginas que existem no meu projeto, sejam mapeadas pelo sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz uma tabela de páginas com parent_id e depois eu faço a busca a seguir com o sitemap montado

```
$this->Paginas->find('treeList',[ 'spacer' => '... '])->toArray();
```